# Codeigniter URL routing

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

After searching a lot around, I decided to post this matter here.

I am working with codeigniter ( latest release). I need to have the URLs of my site working like below.

**[username]** / [controller] / [action] / [parameters]

as you can see the username is leading on the URL rest follows as normal. I need to fetch the username and get some data for the site so that that site could be customized according to his settings.

I tried to achieve this with .htaccess but had no luck. Then I checked with routing on code igniter, but I am not sure whether it's the right solid solution for me. can someone give me any leading on this. is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: post your .htaccess code

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wi


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`


This is what I have now, basically it just removes the index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to use the routing option from Codeigniter. 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['(:any)/user/viewprofile/(:num)'] = controllername/functionname/$2";
```

This way you can build classes and functions in an nicely ordered way.And keep it in codeigniter.

Comment: This is the method I'm currently using now, now I believe this is the way to go, thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['(:any)/controller'] = 'controller/users/$1';
```

This will pass the dynamic username to the controller